# What are "sys.extended_index..." indexes?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

A `CHECKDB` run reports corruption in `sys.extended_index_1066482673_384000`. What kind of index are represented by the name pattern `sys.extended_index_...`? The message is:

> The spatial index, XML index or indexed view 'sys.extended_index_1066482673_384000' (object ID ...) does not contain all rows that the view definition produces.  This does not necessarily represent an integrity issue with the data in this database. For more information about troubleshooting DBCC errors on spatial indexes, XML indexes, and indexed views, see SQL Server Books Online.

Comment: Do you use spatial indexes ? Possibly, you can drop and recreate the object and run checkdb.

Comment: Here, I'm not concerned with resolving the corruption. I want to understand what kinds of objects generate such names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extended Indexes are full text indexes, XML indexes, and Spatial indexes.  Reason, the 3 types of indexes are better handled outside the B+ tree index.

I know you do not care to correct this but, did you recently upgrade?  Try changing the compatibility level if it's not SQL Server 2014 and run `CHECKDB` again

You can identify the table object for the extended index error by using the below code. You may need to tweak the name in the where clause if I have it wrong.

```
SELECT 
    OBJECT_NAME(PARENT_OBJECT_ID) AS table_object,
    name,
    create_date
FROM sys.internal_tables it
WHERE INTERNAL_TYPE = 207
AND it.name = 'extended_index_1066482673_384000'
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Compat level is already max. I will try to rebuild those indexes.

Comment: Hi @boot4life, did rebuilding the index fix your problem?  Thanks!

Comment: No, this is "unfixable" corruption. I still have this (http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/124655/are-unfixable-spatial-index-corruptions-considered-normal) and another, similar EXTENDED_LOGICAL_CHECKS bug as of 12.0.4427.24.